# Java ActionListener Error , Buttons Color Changing Program using popups

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, helper

I'm trying to make a program that changes different colors in frame to the color I choose using a popup menu. I'm getting an error in the ActionListener and without it I can't have an action performed for each colored button.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Graphic.<init>(Graphic.java:43)
    at Graphic.main(Graphic.java:273)
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
public class Graphic extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graphic");
    private JButton [] l;
        private JPopupMenu menu;
        private Toolkit toolkit;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("Selected: " + actionEvent.getActionCommand());
  }
    public Graphic ()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
                JButton l[]=new JButton[9];
                for ( int i=0;i<9;i++ )
                {
        l[i] = new JButton();
        add(l[i]);
                if(i==0)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                else if(i==1)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                else if(i==2)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                else if(i==3)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                else if(i==4)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.PINK);
                else if(i==5)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                else if(i==6)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                else if(i==7)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                else if(i==8)
        l[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                for(JButton j:l)
                {
                    j.addActionListener(this);
                }
                }

        //Create the popup menu.
         //private class ColorListener implements ActionListener{
        final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();

        popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Green") {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        }

       }));

        popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Blue") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            }

        }));
         popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Red") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.RED);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.RED);

            }
        }));
         popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Pink") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.PINK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.PINK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.PINK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.PINK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.PINK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.PINK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.PINK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.PINK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.PINK);

            }
        }));
         popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Gray") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.GRAY);

            }
        }));
         popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Yellow") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

            }
        }));
         popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Cyan") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.CYAN);

            }
        }));
         popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Magenta") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

            }
        }));
         popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Black") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == l[0])
                   l[0].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[1])
                   l[1].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[2])
                   l[2].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[3])
                   l[3].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[4])
                   l[4].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[5])
                   l[5].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[6])
                   l[6].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[7])
                   l[7].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
               else if(e.getSource() == l[8])
                   l[8].setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            }
        }));
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)                
        l[j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });

        }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Graphic g = new Graphic();
        g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        g.setSize(300, 300);
        g.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: dont just dump code and expect someone to fix it

Comment: I'm Not Asking a Fix , I just wanna know what to do to fix it :)

Comment: The inner loop, where you add the ActionListener looks worrying, you couldn't be trying to add ActionListeners to buttons that haven't been initialised yet

Comment: First of all the posted code doesn't even compile because you define the button array twice. Also, the posted code is not formatted properly making the code difficult to read. If you want people to read your code then make the code readable.

Comment: Sorry for that , but i'm still learning Java not a pro , that is why

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this section...

```
            for ( int i=0;i<9;i++ )
            {
                l[i] = new JButton();
                //...
                for(JButton j:l)
                {
                    j.addActionListener(this);
                }
            }
```

Basically, you're inner loop is trying to access elements within your array that haven't been initialised yet...

While you have the opportunity, drop a break point into your code and step through it, this will give you some important experience

Comment: 1+, I almost had my answered entered when I got interrupted by a phone call :) The real question is why does he even have an inner loop. Just add the ActionListener to the button when the button is created. The other problem with the posted code is the `shadowing` of the button array.

Comment: I'll See what to do about this part , thank u guys

but what about the ActionListener for the popup menu ? any idea about it?

Comment: @PrinceQuestiorinos Your popup menu item ActionListener's won't work the way you think they will, because the source of the event is actually the menu item itself. Take a look at setComponentPopupMenu